# GridView download files in Subfolders

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView with data in it, including filenames, I can download files only from one folder and cannot download the files in the subfolders. I have been using this

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) 
{
if (e.CommandName == "Download")
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=" + e.CommandArgument);
    Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("Upload\\Track\\Files") + e.CommandArgument);
    Response.End();
    }
}
```

I have tried adding this, but I get an error stating its illegal.

```
string path = Server.MapPath("\\Upload\\Track\\Files\\ ,*," + SearchOption.AllDirectories);
Response.TransmitFile(path + e.CommandArgument);
```

I want to be able to download all files including the ones in the subfolders, using this method.

UPDATED -- I have also tried this way, but no success, I know I can get the right path, but it just doesn't download.

```
string path = Server.MapPath("\\Upload\\Track\\Files");
string filename = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);

string pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(dir + path);

if (e.CommandName == "Download")
{
System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(path);
if (File.Exists(pathString)) { 
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=" + filename);
Response.TransmitFile(pathString);
Response.End();
```

Comment: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907465/how-can-i-send-the-client-multiple-files-to-download>

Comment: I dont want to download all files at once. Some of the file links in my GridView do not download as the path of the files are in different subfolders

Comment: Does e.CommandArgument contains, just file name or relative path + filename?

Comment: It contains just file name

Comment: that is the problem, you should also bind the relative subfolder path to the CommandArgument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found a solution to my question, I have added a field in my database which holds information about the path - I get this path from when I upload the files, which captures the path and adds it to the database. I have also added the below code to the uploads field in my GridView.

This solution is best for me at the moment, but of course can be improved.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quote" InsertVisible="false">
<ItemTemplate>
<a href="<%# Eval("FilePath") %>/<%# Eval("Uploads") %>"><%# Eval("Uploads") %></a>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```